# Existence of a Complex Valued Arithmetic Function(Miklós-Schweitzer)

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory

For which complex numbers $\alpha$  does there exist a completely multiplicative, complex-valued arithmetic function  such that
$$\sum_{n<x}f(n)= \alpha x +O(1)$$

I think the function has to be real valued and $\alpha$ to be real. Any ideas. Thanks.